# The role of the virtual work principle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, work, constrained-dynamics

Lanczos' masterpiece "The Variational Principle of Mechanics" has, on page 76, the following statement:

> **Postulate A (virtual work):** The virtual work of the forces of reaction is always zero for any virtual displacement which is in
>   harmony with the given kinematic constraints.
>
> This postulate is not restricted to the realm of statics. It applies
>   equally to dynamics, when the principle of virtual work is suitably
>   generalized by means of d'Alembert's principle. Since all the
>   fundamental variational principles of mechanics,  the principles of
>   Euler, Lagrange, Jacobi, Hamilton, are but alternative formulations of
>   d'Alembert's principle, Postulate A is actually the *only* postulate
>   of analytical mechanics, and is thus of fundamental importance$^1$.
>
> $^1$Those scientists who claim that analytical mechanics is nothing
>   but a mathematically different formulation of the laws of Newton must
>   assume that Postulate A is deducible from the Newtonian laws of
>   motion. The author is unable to see how this can be done. Certainly
>   the third law of motion, "action equals reaction", is not wide enough
>   to replace Postulate A.

By "in harmony" he means forces that keep rigid bodies rigid, that is, that don't break the stuff you're studying. In the next chapter he proceeds to prove all of mechanics is deducible from Newton's Second Law and d'Alembert's principle, which is philosophically elaborate, but mathematically resumes to transforming $F = ma$ into $F-ma=0$, which turns dynamics into statics.

I have a feeling something is strange, here. Is the author stating that all analytical mechanics can be obtained from Newton's Second Law + Postulate A?

Comment: Does [this website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_work) help?

Comment: It does help clarifying why the Third Law and the Postulate are related, but I'm still looking for further clarification on the importance of the virtual work principle. Where does the First Law fit?

Comment: "The author is unable to see" is a very suspicious phrase. If the author has this conviction and if he has written "a masterpiece", then that masterpiece has to contain a mathematical proof that the statements are not equivalent. There is no philosophy in this, at all. If you want to see a well written book about mechanics that avoids all the philosophy, read Landau-Lifshitz Volume 1. Having said that, I think they pretty much bypass the general issue and focus on scenarios that are more important than the axiomatics of classical mechanics.

Comment: Indeed, "the author is unable to see" is extremely problematic. I agree and that's why I posted the question. But Lanczos' book covers ten times what Landau's cover, and is the total opposite of that you've suggested: its aim is to be philosophically oriented, and I'm curious about the axioms. Lanczos was not interested in how to calculate stuff, especially in a time where philosophy and physics were still quite mingled, but in finding out the "why"s in a time symplectic geometry didn't exist.

Comment: I am not saying that Lanczos is wrong, but one can't just wipe the issue off the table with such a remark. Technically it boils down to work being a matter of energy conservation, while the third law is about momentum conservation (the second law is silent on both issues). If you take Noether seriously, then Newton's laws are, indeed, incomplete. There should be an energy conservation law for closed systems. That there isn't has a good reason, of course: Newton includes thermodynamics, whereas rigid constraints do not.

Comment: If you want to read a real masterpiece about classical mechanics, confront Arnold.

Comment: CuriousOne - That was a nice remark. Noether is a corollary in analytical mechanics and appears naturally in the Lagrangian formalism, which makes it more easily related to the virtual work postulate than to Newton's laws. 

@Blazej I'm not after book recommendations, but thanks. Also, the best book ever written about Mechanics is not Arnol'd's, its Spivak's, IMHO.

Comment: Noether is far more general than mechanics. It applies to all known physically relevant systems with symmetries. In the end the question boils down to "Are Newton's laws a complete set of axioms for the purposes of analytical mechanics?" and the answer is negative. On the other hand, analytical mechanics is not a complete description of classical physics, either, so we lose with one hand what we are gaining with the other. Newton + TD is a (subtly) different theory than analytical mechanics + statistical mechanics. One wonders why Lanczos doesn't mention that.

Comment: Was Statistical Mechanics a well developed theory by the time Lanczos wrote his book? The first edition appeared in the 40's.

Comment: Pretty much, even though the subtle but mathematically problematic interplay between TD and SM is still being actively researched. I don't think that's relevant here, though. It seems to me that Newton simply doesn't expect energy conservation (we can plug non-conservative forces in all we want), while analytical mechanics does.

Answer (score 0):

I’ll  have a go at this, since we use it in pulley systems.
Basically we consider an imaginary (infinitesimal) displacement dx, and then calculate the total ‘work’ done due to the forces acting on the system. The virtual work (W) theorem allows us to equate this W = 0.

This allows us to add 1 more equation to solve the question, which at times may be necessary or a faster way to solve problems. It is called ‘virtual’ work as there is no real work done, we are assuming one and equating it to 0 to solve a question.

You may want to refer to
https://www.iitg.ac.in/kd/Lecture%20Notes/ME101-Lecture19-KD.pdf

I agree with the last statement made by the author indeed all mechanics can be derived from NLM, for example rotational mechanics, but we have devised other methods to make our work easier. ;)

You may want to have a look at a problem I just made to demonstrate how virtual work method can be used.

[image]
Hope it helps.

Comment: On this site, please avoid screenshots. Your equations are hard to read and you should use the formatting tools made available here. Thanks.

Comment: @Miyase sorry, I didn’t know that. I will try to format next time.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Unfortunately the original question has very little to do with solving problems in mechanics. I asked this question when I was still a first year PhD student, but even after 7 years I still marvel at the depth of the virtual work principle. It might well be the most general statement in the whole of physics!

Comment: @QuantumBrick guess I again tried to answer something beyond my level, I just wanted to give it a try to better my knowledge as well.